# Unordered-list inline vertical alignment and responsive spacing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a responsive navbar for mobile, but I am having trouble getting the link containers to resize properly. I also cannot seem to get the text to center itself vertically. I have tried using auto padding and margins in both cases, but they don't seem to be doing anything. I am using Bootstrap.

My questions are:

1. How do I center the text vertically within its container?
2. How do I get the width of each link's container to be the width of the text
3. How do I then get the spacing between each container to be the same, so that all together they fill the width of the screen?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" id="nav-container-mobile">
                <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline text-center d-flex" id="nav-list-mobile">
                    <li class="list-inline-item text-center nav-link-horizontal" id="nav-profile-link-mobile">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#Profile">
                            <div class="nav-link-container-mobile">Profile</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item text-center nav-link-horizontal" id="nav-experience-link-mobile">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#Experience">
                                <div class="nav-link-container-mobile">Experience</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item text-center nav-link-horizontal" id="nav-skills-link-mobile">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#Skills">
                                <div class="nav-link-container-mobile">Skills</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item text-center nav-link-horizontal" id="nav-project-link-mobile">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#project">
                            <div class="nav-link-container-mobile">Projects</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item text-center nav-link-horizontal" id="nav-contact-link-mobile">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="#Contact">
                            <div class="nav-link-container-mobile">Contact</div>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav-container-mobile {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 70px;
            padding: 0;
            background: #292929;
            z-index: 5;
        }
        #nav-list-mobile {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        .nav-link-horizontal {
            height: 100%;
            width: 15vw;
            min-width: 50px;
        }
        .nav-link-container-mobile {
            padding: auto;
            height: 100%;
            overflow-wrap: break-word;
        }

        .nav-link { 
            color: #aeaeae; 
        }
```

Any help or advice is appreciated.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Uzs6W/663/)

Comment: What Bootstrap version are you trying to use? The fiddle has Bootstrap 3, but your code is for Bootstrap 4.

Comment: Whoops. Bootstrap 4. Looks like I grabbed the wrong CDN link. The JSFiddle has been updated with the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be simpler to use the Bootstrap 4 [Nav Fill or Justify](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#fill-and-justify), and then just change the background color and other styles as needed.

https://www.codeply.com/go/WsWHHIfRlh

```
<div class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark" id="nav-container-mobile">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-100">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="">Experience</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Skills</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

#nav-container-mobile {
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  padding: 0;
  background: #292929;
  z-index: 5;
}

.nav-link { 
  color: #aeaeae; 
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks! Didn't even know nav fill existed.